# Docker: container state exit 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php, containers

i have a problem with docker container.
That's my docker-compose file with 5 services

```
    version: '3'
networks:
  laravel:

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports: 
      - "8088:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html 
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on: 
    - mysql
    - php

    networks: 
    - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "4306:3306"
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql

    networks: 
    - laravel

  php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks: 
      - laravel

  redis:
        image: redis:5.0.0-alpine
        restart: always
        container_name: redis
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        networks:
          - laravel
  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    networks:
      - laravel
```

then i run

> docker-compose up -d

and then

> docker-compose ps

to see my container and i always get the composer contaier down with code 0. that's the screenshot

[image]:

can someone explain me why i can't put this container up. Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you expect the container to do?

Comment: @tkausl how can i put the composer container up? like mysql nginx php and redis

Comment: It's not a server. It won't stay "up". It will run and exit. There is no advantage on having a composer "container". An image can be useful, but a container, doubtful. It seems you may be confused about what you want to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composer` isn't a program that stays alive. It's a program that does specific some work and then exits.

There's not much purpose in keeping it "up", since it's not going to do anything like the other processes do (nginx intercepts web traffic and writes response, mysql accepts database connections and reads/writes from a database, php serves web content, redis can be connected to as a cache).